# Is homology dual to cohomology or is homotopy dual to cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I thought it was `homology` that is dual to `cohomology`. But reading `Bott & Tu` I am now confused. In the intro, page 2 and onwards, it briefly describes a dual point of view and the relation between homotopy and cohomology. It sounds like homotopy and cohomology are *dual* to each other, although it is not precisely defined.

For example, at the bottom of page 2, it says "the two concepts are dual to each other". The question is, is this saying `homotopy` and `cohomology` are dual to each other in general, or is it just that the concepts are "somewhat dual" to each other? Are they *dual* to each other and if so in which sense and to what extent?

Comment: You should be more precise: What sentence makes you confused? Include the relevant text excerpt in the question, and people will better understand your confusion.

Comment: Strictly speaking, cohomology is not quite dual to homology, there is a correction term (with the Ext functor)  in the universal coefficients theorem (you only get a short exact sequence).

Comment: @Trebor I added more details including where I found it unclear in the book. Thank you!

Comment: "It sounds like" does not explain the source of your confusion. What makes you think of duality of homotopy and cohomology? Did you try to work out some simple examples such as tori?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see. I have added more specific quote and questions. Hope this time it is clearer. Thanks.

Comment: If you read the text more closely, on page 2 they only talk about duality of $\pi_0$ and $H^0$. Once you learn a bit more about homotopy groups and cohomology groups, you see that they are not dual in any sense.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Exactly, only the "duality" of $\pi_0$ and $H^0$ are mentioned, and without a precise definition of what "duality" is. It didn't say for higher groups if or not there is a "dual". But it mentioned that much of homotopy is learned through cohomology, hence the question if they are dual or not in general. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Homotopy and cohomology are dual in a vague sense called "[Eckmann-Hilton duality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eckmann-Hilton+duality)". As the linked page says, this is more a heuristic rather than a precise notion of duality. Certainly in the formal mathematical sense of vector space duality, then homology/cohomology are trying to be dual to each other (and this is achieved when working with field coefficients and finite CW complexes, for example). Homotopy/cohomology are dual in the sense that homotopy groups are determined by homotopy classes of maps out of spheres, and spheres have just a single nonvanishing reduced cohomology group; "dually," cohomology groups are determined by homotopy classes of maps into certain spaces called Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces, which have just a single nonvanishing homotopy group. If we write $S^n$ for a sphere, as usual, and $K_n$ for an Eilenberg-Mac Lane space, we have this informal notion of duality with
$$
[S^n, -] \quad \longleftrightarrow \quad [-, K_n].
$$